# Using REST I am unable to iterate through response data of one call and use in a second call mediator

Tags: rest, wso2-esb

Using WSO2 ESB

I have a need to call a rest service and iterate through its response looking for nested values. With the response of the first call I would like to call a second service and provide data received from the first service.

Given the configuration sample below;

- The call to the first service is successful, returning one or more Destination values
- When iterating through the response of the first call I can see the Destination data through the Log Mediator
- Calls to the second Call Mediator do not place data I am seeing in the Log Mediator in the second endpoint {uri.var.destination}

It appears that I am missing how to grab data from the first call and place it within subsequent calls to the second http endpoint as evidenced by my second Call Mediator sending the following i_param2={uri.var.destination} and I expected it to be i_param2=41st & Oak

Any suggestions and points are much appreciated.

Here is a snip of my API sorry for being so verbose but I wanted to show the service chaining in case it was my config that was causing problems:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/updatebusdisplay" name="UpdateBusDisplay" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <resource methods="GET" protocol="http" url-mapping="/foo">
    <inSequence>
      <call>
        <endpoint>
          <http method="get" trace="disable" uri-template="http://api.translink.ca/rttiapi/v1/stops/50641/estimates?apikey=REMOVED&amp;count=1&amp;timeframe=1440"/>
        </endpoint>
      </call>
      <iterate expression="//Destination" id="it1" preservePayload="true">
        <target>
          <sequence>
            <property description="" expression="//Destination/text()"
              name="uri.var.destination" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log description="" level="full">
              <property expression="get-property('uri.var.destination')" name="property_name"/>
            </log>
            <call>
              <endpoint>
                <http method="get" trace="disable" uri-template="http://jupiter.signage.me/WebService/sendCommand.ashx?i_userpass=REMOVED&amp;i_stationId=41&amp;i_command=event&amp;i_param1=nameone&amp;i_param2={uri.var.destination}"/>
              </endpoint>
            </call>
            <log level="full"/>
          </sequence>
        </target>
      </iterate>
    </inSequence>
```

Copy of the console with wirelog showing the values in each call and the response from the first call, i've removed much of the log to keep it small(er):

```
[2016-01-10 00:45:04,423] DEBUG - wire >> "GET /updatebusdisplay/foo  HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2016-01-10 00:45:04,555] DEBUG - wire << "GET /rttiapi/v1/stops/50641/estimates?apikey=REMOVED&count=1&timeframe=1440 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
...REMOVED...
[2016-01-10 00:45:04,666] DEBUG - wire >> "<NextBuses xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><NextBus><RouteNo>041</RouteNo><RouteName>JOYCE STN/CROWN/UBC           </RouteName><Direction>EAST</Direction><RouteMap><Href>http://nb.translink.ca/geodata/041.kmz</Href></RouteMap><Schedules><Schedule><Pattern>EB22</Pattern><Destination>41ST &amp; OAK</Destination><ExpectedLeaveTime>12:48am</ExpectedLeaveTime><ExpectedCountdown>3</ExpectedCountdown><ScheduleStatus>-</ScheduleStatus><CancelledTrip>false</CancelledTrip><CancelledStop>false</CancelledStop><AddedTrip>false</AddedTrip><AddedStop>false</AddedStop><LastUpdate>11:46:02 pm</LastUpdate></Schedule></Schedules></NextBus></NextBuses>"
[2016-01-10 00:45:04,687]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:774ccb2b-4723-4fa9-88a5-13e9eab588e0, Direction: request, property_name = 41ST & OAK, Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><NextBuses xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><NextBus><RouteNo>041</RouteNo><RouteName>JOYCE STN/CROWN/UBC           </RouteName><Direction>EAST</Direction><RouteMap><Href>http://nb.translink.ca/geodata/041.kmz</Href></RouteMap><Schedules><Schedule><Pattern>EB22</Pattern><ExpectedLeaveTime>12:48am</ExpectedLeaveTime><ExpectedCountdown>3</ExpectedCountdown><ScheduleStatus>-</ScheduleStatus><CancelledTrip>false</CancelledTrip><CancelledStop>false</CancelledStop><AddedTrip>false</AddedTrip><AddedStop>false</AddedStop><LastUpdate>11:46:02 pm</LastUpdate></Schedule></Schedules></NextBus></NextBuses></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2016-01-10 00:45:04,764] DEBUG - wire << "GET /WebService/sendCommand.ashx?i_userpass=REMOVED&i_stationId=41&i_command=event&i_param1=nameone&i_param2={uri.var.destination} HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
```

Comment: That should work according to the example @ https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/HTTP+Endpoint . Perhaps because the property contains white spaces , and an endpoint can't.

Answer (score 0):

As identified by @JavaMasterRSA (many thanks) the problem was related to my data containing invalid characters.

The following is helpful [URI- template encoding in WSO2 ESB for reserved characters](http://waysandmeans.blogspot.ca/2015/05/uri-template-encoding-in-wso2-apim-for.html?m=1)